# How To Build a DrScheme Teach Pack

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm learning PLT Scheme and I want to know how can I build a Teach Pack for DrScheme, some tutorials...? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean bundling DrScheme and a few tutorials together?

Comment: No, go at the menu Language -> Choose Language..., it's this that I want to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A teachpack is just a module file, which can provide any bindings you need.  In any case, this requires knowing how to write a PLT module, and it's a subject that is better to discuss on the [PLT mailing list](http://plt-scheme.org/maillist).